# Generic typealias in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

In haskell you can do this:

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]
```

I tried to make something similar in Swift. So far I wrote these codes with no luck.

```
typealias Parser<A> = String -> [(A, String)]
typealias Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]
typealias Parser = String -> [(A, String)]
```

So is this simply impossible in swift? And if it is is there another ways to implement this behavior?

**UPDATE:** It seems generic typealiases are now supported in swift 3
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Generic `typealias` can be used since Swift 3.0. This should work for you:

```
typealias Parser<A> = (String) -> [(A, String)]
```

Here is the full documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/typealias-declaration

Usage (from @Calin Drule comment):

```
func parse<A>(stringToParse: String, parser: Parser)
```

Comment: Usage:   > func parse<A>(stringToParse: String, parser: Parser)

Answer (score 37):

`typealias` cannot currently be used with generics. Your best option might be to wrap the parser function inside a struct.

```
struct Parser<A> {
    let f: String -> [(A, String)]
}
```

You can then use the trailing closure syntax when creating a parser, e.g.

```
let parser = Parser<Character> { string in return [head(string), tail(string)] }
```

Comment: @mustafa Hi, could you please tell me which part of it denotes Boxing? You didn't mean Boxing in a Java sense, did you? Also, I have a problem wrapping my head around  `[head(string)...` and `tail(string)]`. Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig Boxing refers to wrapping one type around another in order to take advantage of capabilities only found in the outer type. You may be familiar with the concept from Objective-C, where primitives such as integers cannot be passed into an NSArray without being "boxed" in an NSNumber, e.g., `@(1234)`.  The head/tail thing is not swift specific, but rather a common pattern for splitting an array into the first item (the head) and the remaining items (the tail). See http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/swift-tricks.html

Comment: @clozach Thanks for explanation. I will go ahead and go through the link you shared.

Comment: This answer is not up to date. You should check https://stackoverflow.com/a/39779643/590864

Answer (score 6):

#### Generic Type Aliases - [SE-0048](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0048-generic-typealias.md)

Status: Implemented (Swift 3)

> The solution is straight-forward: allow type aliases to introduce type parameters, which are in scope for their definition. This allows one to express things like:

```
typealias StringDictionary<T> = Dictionary<String, T>
typealias IntFunction<T> = (T) -> Int
typealias MatchingTriple<T> = (T, T, T)
alias BackwardTriple<T1, T2, T3> = (T3, T2, T1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am presenting example for **typealias** that demonistrate you to how to use **typealias** in protocols definitions: I hope this helps you understand typealias

```
protocol NumaricType {
    typealias elementType
    func plus(lhs : elementType, _ rhs : elementType) -> elementType
    func minus(lhs : elementType, _ rhs : elementType) -> elementType
}

struct Arthamatic :NumaricType {

    func addMethod(element1 :Int, element2 :Int) -> Int {
       return plus(element1, element2)
    }
    func minusMethod(ele1 :Int, ele2 :Int) -> Int {
        return minus(ele1, ele2)
    }

    typealias elementType = Int

    func plus(lhs: elementType,  _ rhs: elementType) -> elementType {
        return lhs + rhs
    }
    func minus(lhs: elementType, _ rhs: elementType) -> elementType {
        return lhs - rhs
    }
}
```

Output:

```
let obj =  Arthamatic().addMethod(34, element2: 45) // 79
```

Comment: Hey @Narendra G Do you thing this solution could work for Other numerical types as well?