# Cannot invoke 'handler' with argument list of type '([Post])'

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I both do, and don't get why the last line of this playground throws a compiler error:

```
protocol Model { }

struct Post: Model {
  var content = "Hello"
}

struct Posts: Model {
  var allPosts: [Post] = [Post(), Post(), Post()]
}

func handler(items: [Model]) { }

var posts = Posts()
handler(posts.posts)
```

If you're reading between the lines, my goal is to be able to invoke a function with an argument that is an array of structs that conform to a protocol. The function should be able to deal with arrays of different types of structs. Would love to know what I'm missing, and if you have a suggestion for a better solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Your handler function is expecting a array of Model and you are passing a array of Post you need to change it to func handler(items: [Post]) { }

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help for my case. As I mentioned in my post, I have this hard requirement: The function should be able to deal with arrays of different types of structs

Comment: Sorry I miss that, in that case you need to use generics as recommended by @Lei Wang, but the opposite if what he said it is not a limitation but a powerful tool in swift. More details here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be `Swift` limitations. But you can do some workaround like this using `Generics`:

```
func handler<T: Model>(items: [T]) { }
```

or else make your protocol a `@objc` protocol which you can only apply to class type:

```
@objc protocol Model { }

class Post: Model {
    var content = "Hello"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Lei! That definitely resolves it. I have a follow-up question if you have any ideas: how would you apply this technique to a typealias? My handler function isn't actually a function but a typealias (i.e. typealias CompletionHandler = ([Model]?) -> Void. Or is this a limitation, too, and would I have to do something like boxing (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084586/generic-typealias-in-swift)?

Comment: @Lei Wrang, this is not a limitation in swift, this is actually a very powerful tool that was introduced in swift called Generics.

Comment: @IcaroNZ well, I think a struct conforming the protocol should be accepted in this case. And if the input parameter is not an array, it will work.

Comment: @IcaroNZ I thin that downcasting an array of object to an array of protocol may require Objective-C involving.

Comment: @rainypixels `typealias` does not work in generics. Maybe boxing is a good choice in that case.

Comment: @LeiWang what's happen is that a array and a dictionary in Object-C use to have just one type, now in Swift you can have many types in the same array or dictionary. If you downcast to Object-C you just say to the compiler I am using just one type in this array so don't worry